# createHTMLNotification() replacement

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created a Chrome extension in which it uses `createHTMLNotification()` to show a window on top of everything. However, starting from Chrome 28 Google decided to drop `createHTMLNotification()` entirely (why, Google. Why?). All in a sudden I need to find a replacement.

`createHTMLNotification()` let me to dynamically change things on the notification. However, I don't think the new Rich Notification let me do that.

Is there any work-around or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: If you don't need fancy styling, but just an image, header and body, use `webkitNotifications.createNotification(iconURL, head, body);` and `.show()` / `.close()` to replace content.

Comment: On Mac OS X when using `webkitNotifications.createNotification` the icon will always be Chrome icon. There seems to be no way around this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little bit thinking, I still didn't want to be stuck with Google's default layout. So I used the `image` type notification, and put a generated canvas image on it. I can draw whatever I want, and I also created a little API to update the notification whenever I want. This worked out perfectly for me.

<sub>Thank you Google for making everything so complicated...</sub>

Comment: I have the same problem - notifications my extension is creating are interactive and can't be replaced using any default template. So, you are saying that I can create a canvas and catch and react to any clicks on it?

Comment: @KonradDzwinel - Unfortunately, it will not be able to catch any user action other than a [simple click event (without coordinates)](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html#event-onClicked). The best you can do is to use the button feature, which has a maximum of 2 buttons per notification.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! For me, two buttons and a clickable image are still not enough. Have you considered opening a standard popup (`window.open`)?

Comment: @KonradDzwinel - Yes, but it won't work in my case because it doesn't look like a notification, and it doesn't stay on top. Therefore I stick with the notification API just to give it a native look.

Answer (score 5):

The change was actually [announced properly on the Chromium-Extensions mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/chromium-extensions/XbzPo6QbW7A). There was apparently some misunderstanding though, it was stated in [august last year](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+GoogleChromeDevelopers/posts/8vWo8hq4pDm) that it would remain in use for extensions, but that only lasted half a year.

Anyway, the official recommended replacement is the [Rich Notifications API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications.html). There is no other workaround planned.

Comment: IMO they should just leave the HTML notification alone, or at least notify us and give us more time to switch to the new rich notification.

Comment: As said, the formal EOL notification was in august 2012, but they weren't clear back then on whether it would also eventually affect extension developers. There's more pissed off people on the interwebs on this subject from what I found  :)

Comment: Is there any place we can all complain about this? Any open crbug?