# Customize / Style a Desktop Notification

Tags: javascript, css, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I got a desktop notification using HTML5 up and running. However, the look and feel of the Desktop Notification seems too simple for my requirement.

Basically, the Desktop notification, as of now is just a simple Text message with a white background on a rectangle.

Below is the code i have used for displaying the Desktop notification:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Notification HTML5</title>
<script>
function notifyMe() {
  // Let's check if the browser supports notifications
  if (!("Notification" in window)) {
    alert("This browser does not support desktop notification");
  }

  // Let's check if the user is okay to get some notification
  else if (Notification.permission === "granted") {
    // If it's okay let's create a notification
  var options = {
        body: "This is the body of the notification",
        //icon: "icon.jpg",
        dir : "ltr"
    };
  var notification = new Notification("Hi there",options);
  notification.onclick = function () {
    //console.log("this:"+this);
      //window.open("https://stackoverflow.com/");
      Maximize();
    };
  }

  // Otherwise, we need to ask the user for permission
  // Note, Chrome does not implement the permission static property
  // So we have to check for NOT 'denied' instead of 'default'
  else if (Notification.permission !== 'denied') {
    Notification.requestPermission(function (permission) {
      // Whatever the user answers, we make sure we store the information
      if (!('permission' in Notification)) {
        Notification.permission = permission;
      }

      // If the user is okay, let's create a notification
      if (permission === "granted") {
        var options = {
              body: "This is the body of the notification",
              //icon: "icon.jpg",
              dir : "ltr"
          };
        var notification = new Notification("Hi there",options);
      }
    });
  }

  // At last, if the user already denied any notification, and you
  // want to be respectful there is no need to bother them any more.
}
function Maximize() 
{
window.innerWidth = screen.width;
window.innerHeight = screen.height;
window.screenX = 0;
window.screenY = 0;
alwaysLowered = false;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="notifyMe()" style="height: 80px;width: 311px;color:white;font-size: 24px;background: cadetblue;border: none;cursor: pointer;">Show me notification</button><br><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is the image illustrating the way in which the Desktop notification is rendered:

[image]

So my query is:

Is it possible to apply some styling to the appearance of the Desktop notification? Like displaying the font in Bold and italics and in a different colour and changing the background color of the Notification and may be rounding the corners of the rectangular Notification pop-up?

What i tried:

I learnt that previously we did have a way of doing this. That is by using the API `createHTMLNotification()`, but now the same has been deprecated. Also, i tried finding alternatives for the same [Replacement for createHTMLNotification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16764882/createhtmlnotification-replacement), but it lack's clarity.

Comment: Maybe this is helpfull to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833814/styling-html5-desktop-notifications

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:google-chrome-extension]? The question never mentions extensions and the code you show cannot work in an extension.

Comment: @Xan: Only reason to add that tag is to get suggestions from those who have worked on Google Chrome extensions. Is there a way to achieve this in google-chrome-extensions ?

Comment: To a certain limited extent. You don't get full control over the layout, only a few more options. See https://developer.chrome.com/apps/richNotifications for some samples.